# Error calling drawShape in Gnu Octave

Tags: ubuntu, octave

I just installed the octave-geometry package, and tried calling:

```
drawShape('rect', [20 20 40 10 pi/3]);
```

Result is:

```
error: 'rectAsPolygon' undefined near line 78 column 21
error: called from
    drawShape at line 78 column 19
```

I'm running Linux Mint 17 (Qiana).  Initially, I installed via apt-get, which uses octave 3.8, and got similar results.  So, I installed octave version 4.0, taking the following route:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable
```

GUI installed okay, but I still can't use geometry package.

```
>> pkg load geometry;
>> ver
----------------------------------------------------------------------
GNU Octave Version: 4.0.0
GNU Octave License: GNU General Public License
Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Package Name  | Version | Installation directory
--------------+---------+-----------------------
     general  |   2.0.0 | /usr/share/octave/packages/general-2.0.0
    geometry *|   2.1.0 | /home/jack/octave/geometry-2.1.0
```

Any ideas?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the geometry package. You should report it on Octave's [bug tracker](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave)

Comment: bugreport: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?47144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now fixed in the developing version https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/geometry/ci/default/tree/

Comment: Ok, sounds good, thanks.  <br/> Sorry for the delayed response, but I've been busy since I asked this question.